# CORONA SDK Physics that dont affect every sprite

Tags: coronasdk

I want to make some sprites affected by physics gravity, but not all of them in the display screen. For example, the player don't need to be affected and, when collision with another, this one leaves another sprite object that will be affected.

Sorry for my english i'm foreign and try to explain better I can do.

Thanks!!!.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread out,

[Collision Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200505/avoiding-collision-in-corona-sdk)

or check for collision filtering and masking bits.

Comment: it's more about physics and gravity than collisions, but thanks i'll go to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/gravityScale.html
Setting gravityScale for a physics body to zero makes it unaffected by gravity.
myObj.gravityScale = 0

Setting it to a negative value makes it "float", for example if you want a balloon going up :)