# Generating physics object at the same point of another object and move generated object without colliding with the second in corona sdk

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I want to generate two physics object at the same point and then move one physics object by applying the force, but as one object moves it collides with the other physics object. I can't make the other object as non-physics because further these object will collide with each other but initially they must not collide.Some of the coding part which i have done is below ... please suggest any idea.. thanks

```
local obj2
local physicsbody1= { density=0.1, friction=0, bounce=0 }
local physicsbody2= {density=10.0, friction=0, bounce=0.1, radius=25 }

local function createobj2(_xpos,y_pos,_id)
obj2=display.newImage("obj2.png")
obj2.x=_xpos
obj2.y=_ypos
physics.addBody(obj2,physicsbody1)
end


local physicsObjStatic=display.newImage("img1.png")
physicsObjStatic.x=450
physicsObjStatic.y=200
physics.addBody(physicsObjStatic,physicsbody2)


    local function Shot( event )
        local t = event.target

        local phase = event.phase
        if "began" == phase then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
            t.isFocus = true
            t:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
            t.angularVelocity = 0

            target.x = t.x
            target.y = t.y

            startRotation = function()
            target.rotation = target.rotation + 4
            end

            Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", startRotation )

        local showTarget = transition.to( target, { alpha=0.4, xScale=0.4, yScale=0.4, time=200 } )
            myLine = nil

        elseif t.isFocus then
            if "moved" == phase then
                 if ( myLine ) then
                    myLine.parent:remove( myLine ) 
                end
                myLine = display.newLine( t.x,t.y, event.x,event.y )
                myLine:setColor( 255, 255, 255, 50 )
                myLine.width = 8

            elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then

                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                t.isFocus = false

                local stopRotation = function()
                    Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", startRotation )
                end

                local hideTarget = transition.to( target, { alpha=0, xScale=1.0, yScale=1.0, time=200, onComplete=stopRotation } )

                if ( myLine ) then
                    myLine.parent:remove( myLine )
                end
createobj2(t.x,t.y)
obj2:applyForce( (t.x - event.x), (t.y - event.y), t.x, t.y )
            end
        end
        return true
    end
physicsObjStatic:addEventListener( "touch", Shot )
```

Comment: "Please give me the solution" is not likely to work. Show us what you tried (but only include relevant fragments sufficient enough for us to run the code) and describe what doesn't work. This also allows those that have Corona to run your fragment (if they want) to test what you are describing.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200505/avoiding-collision-in-corona-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You should temporarily change your dragged object to kinematic instead of dynamic while it's being dragged.  Kinematic objects do not generate collisions.

Comment: Is there any another way to solve this issue because this solution does not suits to the situation of my game. Actually both objects are generated from the same point and if i move one object it collides with the other i don't want to remove physics from the objects or change it to kinematic... thanks  for your help

Comment: You can look into collision filters.  There are several forum posts and community created tutorials on using them.